# Download whole directory(folder) from sharepoint using vba-excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I want to download all the files that are under:

http://sharepoint.company.com/sites/Some Site/Some Directory

to a local directory with vba and excel. I found another question and their answers were saying that I need to map this directory to a drive but I am not able to do so. I know how to download a file from that directory if I know the name of the file but I can't download the whole directory.

Is there a way of doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the [WebDAV (Explorer view) interface](http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2010/01/03/all-about-explorer-view-in-sharepoint.aspx) is not usable by the normal FileSystemObject

See this similar question 
[Get the content of a sharepoint folder with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba)

The this [link](http://blog.itwarlocks.com/2009/04/28/accessing-webdav-in-microsoft-word-visual-basic/) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba/1637481#1637481) has some code that hacks into WebDav using ADO...
An interesting take on the solution.

Comment: My problem is that the path that I want to download (the folder) is in the form of http://... and when I am using the FileSystemObject etc I get a "path not found" messsage (although the path exists). Probably, the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" does not work with "http://..." type of folders. The other option would be to try to map that location to a drive letter (e.g. A: ) and then try to use it as a "normal" folder but I did not manage to do that either... Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried to use the mapping that is mentioned in the links provided above but I get the following error message when trying to map the drive: "No network provider accepted the given network path.". Any ideas on why this is happenning?