# Error 76 - path not found, using FileSystemObject.GetFolder() with SharePoint address

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

**What could be going on here?**

I'm using:

```
Dim FOL As folder
Dim fs As New FileSystemObject

Set FOL = fs.GetFolder("//mycompany.sharepoint.com/etc/etc/")
```

And on my laptop it's working perfectly.
Last week, it worked on my colleague's laptop perfectly. This week, it works on mine but it doesn't work on my colleague's! It gives a run-time 76 : 'Path not found' error.

We've both tried pasting the link directly in to an IE browser and it connects fine. So **what could have changed** between last week and this week to make it stop working on my colleagues' yet still work OK on mine?

One additional piece of info: On my browser in SharePoint **I have the option to "Open with Windows Explorer" but my colleague doesn't.**

EDIT: I believe my question is different to the similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba) because this WAS working and now it wasn't. I'm asking what could have changed and is it linked to the lack of Action "Open with Windows Explorer".

Comment: perhaps map the network location as a drive and reference the drive. All I can think of, I would normally say it's network related but if you can access it in IE then it's not. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the content of a sharepoint folder with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the SharePoint folder to a drive letter.

This solution is discussed here:
[Get the content of a sharepoint folder with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba)