# Trying to copy files to Sharepoint 365 site in VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint

My company migrated our Sharepoint to 365 and now the UNC paths don't work.

How can I use VBA to copy files using the Sharepoint URL, or is there something I'm missing when I convert the URL to UNC? I tried adding @SSL to the end of the domain which didn't work.

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

fso.CopyFile SourcePath, WebPath, True
```

Comment: In short, Sharepoint is not part of the FileSystem, so this is not going to be as straightforward as you are hoping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba

Comment: I'm gonna try this SOAP method since I don't think mapping will work for me with multiple users needing to copy the files
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/5965619e-8d58-42f0-9504-d27b1eaf6b5b/vba-code-to-connect-to-sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointdevelopment