# VBA and MDB database both in SharePoint. How to set connection?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am fairly new to coding in VBA so finding this quite complex to resolve.

Background: I have a folder hierarchy in SharePoint with each folder having Excel files. I am trying to copy all the data from the Excels file and store in .mdb database. I have mad an Excel file(VBA) which also has a search functionality querying this database.

Current Situation: I was able to sync this SharePoint to my OneDrive and had access to these files in my WE. I setup the VBA code and the .mdb database in the same directory and was able to achieve this task.

Problem: Other who have access to this SharePoint location are not able to use this search functionality because for them the path does not exist.

Is there any way I can make this work? (I tried following a [DriveMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba) code but htis doesnt work for me either. Error: Network name cannot be found.)

I am really stuck on it and would appreciate some help. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by "use this search functionality"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got to find the answer for this query after digging for a while.
`fPath = Environ("HOMEDRIVE") + Environ("HOMEPATH") + "...."`. This way the file path can be dynamically updated to reflect each user's homedrive and path. Hope it helps others seeking similar solution.