# VBA Dir on SharePoint -why working only with Internet Explorer?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I wanted to map some folders on SharePoint and create new subfolders via VBA. The SharePointURLtoUNC function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba) was really useful but there was another prerequisite for making all kinds of Dir commands work: I had to log in under Internet Explorer into SharePoint. It didn't work when I was only logged in under Chrome or Microsoft Edge.
Could you please explain why is it so and how to avoid Internet Explorer login?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to know how to implement map a network drive to SharePoint, right? If this is the case, the issue you are experiencing is the correct behavior.

When you're mapping a network drive to a SharePoint document library:

1. The steps that require a web browser must be performed in Internet Explorer (version 10 or 11).
2. A mapped drive is only available when you're online.
3. Performance depends on connectivity speed.
4. To maintain the mapped network drive after it's established, you should periodically (say, every two weeks) navigate to the SharePoint library in Internet Explorer. This action refreshes an underlying "security token" that gives you permission to have the network drive mapped to the online library.

In addition, it's important to note that this is legacy technology and it may be affected by the deprecation of Internet Explorer in August 2021. For more details. please refer to this doc: [Map a network drive to a SharePoint library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-a-network-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-751148de-f579-42f9-bc8c-fcd80ccf0f53#ie).