# Run macro for all Workbooks in a Sharepoint folder

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have written a macro to produce a report, which works perfectly but I need to run it for all files saved in a SharePoint folder. Currently this involves opening each workbook (aproximately 30), running the macro and then saving-as back to the folder with "summary" appended to the file name.

Is there a way of running my macro for all Workbooks in the Sharepoint folder and saving to the same location? I have Googled this problem extensively but could only find solutions that work with mapped drives, rather than SharePoint https:// links.

Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

TE

Comment: [This may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba)

Comment: I'm starting to think SharePoint is Microsoft's way to get us all to finally stop using VBA.

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad - I did actually come across this when Googling solutions. However, due to recent changes, I don't think the Internet Exporer method works anymore because when you launch it, it now opens Edge - although this does have an option to "open page in Internet Explorer mode".

Comment: @TimWilliams I think you're right!