# Writing text file to a SharePoint folder with VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-project

I am using MS Project VBA code to create a text file in a folder on my desktop and also in a folder on SharePoint when there is the need.

```vb
Dim t                       As Task
Dim td                      As TaskDependency
Dim str                     As String
Dim sep                     As String
Dim i                       As Long
Dim fso                     As Object
Dim f                       As Object
Dim SharepointAddress       As String
Dim LocalAddress            As String
Dim Address                 As String

' Create Local and SharePoint address.
LocalAddress = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Test"
SharepointAddress = "https://Company.sharepoint.com/the_rest_of_the_path"

' Preparing the sharepoint address
SharepointAddress = SharePointURLtoUNC(SharepointAddress)

' print the sharepoint address to immediate window for checking
Debug.Print SharepointAddress

' Use the Address variable for switching between the local address and sharepoint address
Address = SharepointAddress

' If the user pressed the cancel button exit
If MsgBox("Your project data Is being exported. Press OK To continue", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub

Else
    ' Create a fso object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
    ' If the folder exists write the text file to the local or sharepoint address
    If fso.folderexists(Address) Then
        Address = Address & "\mydata.txt"
        Set f = fso.opentextfile(Address, 2, True, -1)      ' The problem is here
    Else
        MsgBox "Connection Is Not established, please try again later"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
End If
```

I can create the file on the folder on my desktop.

When it gets to the SharePoint folder, there are times the file is not created though there is a connection to SharePoint folder, and I am browsing it in my explorer.

I changed the SharePoint address with the SharePointURLtoUNC function that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba)  but I still have this problem.

Comment: In the above code, as it stands, you only create a local file, never a SharePoint file ... is this your full code?

Comment: @JohnM sorry, I corrected the code and the problem persists