# Command Button Save As -Need to go to a specific file path to save and automatically populate the file name

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to have a "template" that will save as a new document when you click the command button. I have figured out to save as but I want it to automatically go to a specific folder and i want the name of the file to autopopulate based on what is already in the folder in numerical order. So every time you click the button it goes 1, then 2, then 3rd and so on.

This is the current VBA code i am using - which allows me to click it and it will save as the document as a normal word document. I just dont know how to make it automatically pull up the folder i want it saved into or to autopopulate the name of the document.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 
    CommandButton1.Select
    Selection.Delete
 
    MsgBox ("Compiling New RCA Submission.")

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .Show
        
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            ThisDocument.SaveAs2 .SelectedItems(1), wdFormatXMLDocument
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox ("New RCA submitted.")
      
 
End Sub
```

[image: highlighted cells to be the file name]

I want the name of the file to be HOLD/Reference number_Product Description_Product Date Code - # (the number being the number of entries using this command button)

- for example: the fourth entry using this command button would automatically put a 4 at the end of the file name.

Comment: What's the `specific folder`? Is it (snapshot) the only table in word template doc?

Answer (score 0):

Assume it is the first table in word template document.

```vb
Sub DEMO()
    Dim sRefNum As String, sProDes As String, sProCode As String
    Dim sPath As String, sFnBase As String
    Dim sFileName, sChar As String
    Dim iIndex As Long, Idx As Long
    sPath = "D:\temp\test\" ' update as needed
    sChar = Chr(13) & Chr(7)
    With ThisDocument.Tables(1) ' updat if it is not the first table
        sRefNum = Split(Replace(.Cell(4, 1).Range.Text, sChar, ""), ":")(1)
        sProDes = Split(Replace(.Cell(6, 1).Range.Text, sChar, ""), ":")(1)
        sProCode = Split(Replace(.Cell(7, 1).Range.Text, sChar, ""), ":")(1)
    End With
    sFnBase = Join(Array(sRefNum, sProDes, sProCode, ""), "_")
    sFileName = Dir(sPath & sFnBase & "*.docx")
    iIndex = 0
    Do While sFileName <> ""
        Idx = Val(Replace(sFileName, sFnBase, ""))
        If Idx > iIndex Then iIndex = Idx
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop
    sFileName = sPath & sFnBase & (iIndex + 1) & ".docx"
    ThisDocument.SaveAs2 sFileName, wdFormatXMLDocument
    MsgBox ("New RCA submitted.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that works but it automatically saves it in my personal and i dont know how to save it to a shared drive.
This is the path i am using: "C:\Users\victoria.chavez\XX Company \Phoenix QC - Documents"
how do it get it to not go to my personal and go to the shared folder instead?

Comment: `sPath = "C:\Users\victoria.chavez\XX Company\Phoenix QC - Documents\" ` please double check the space in path, to make sure it is exactly same as your env.

Comment: I don't want it to go to Users\victoria.chavez though. I dont know how to get it straight to the path? Do i need to use the web path?

Comment: What's the web path? What's kind of shared folder? Is it mapped as a driver which has a driver letter?

Comment: https://XXcorp.sharepoint.com/sites/PhoenixQC/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FPhoenixQC%2FShared%20Documents%2FRoot%20Cause%20Analysis&viewid=ae2c0463%2D5fd7%2D4d4a%2Db113%2D6257321d8b67

Comment: Please refers to [Get the content of a sharepoint folder with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba)